# Least squares estimators in alternative formulation of linear regression

Tags: regression, least-squares

I am being given the expected response in a linear regression model in the form: $E[Y_i|x_i] = \gamma + \beta(x_i - \bar{x})$ and asked to calculate least squares estimators for $\gamma$ and $\beta$. To do so, I write down the sum of squares, take the derivative with respect to each estimator and compare it to zero (as I know that the LS estimators minimize the sum of squares).

$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^N \{ y_i - E[Y_i|x_i]  \}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \{ y_i - \gamma - \beta(x_i - \bar{x})  \}^2$$

Starting with gamma:
$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \gamma} = -2\sum_{i=1}^N \{ y_i - \gamma - \beta(x_i - \bar{x})  \} = 0$. This is the moment that I get stuck in. I know the answer is $\widehat{\gamma} = \bar{y}$ but I'm not sure what happens to the $\sum_{i=1}^N -\beta(x_i - \bar{x})$ bit. It would appear that it is equal to zero? However, I am not sure why.

Comment: The term $\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_{i}-\bar{x})=\frac{N}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}-N\bar{x}=N\bar{x}-N\bar{x}=0$

Comment: Yeah okay, I think i get it now. $\sum y_i - N\gamma - \beta(\sum x_i - N\bar{x}) = 0$ and then I get that $\widehat{\gamma} = \frac{\sum y_i}{N} = \bar{y}$ because the other term disappears. Cheers!